# How to download items and images for them from url (JSON)

Tags: json, swift

Asked 1 question on this site (dont get angry if i cant explain.
I have URL where stored a dict with "category of shopItems" : Array of ShopItems.
Need to download this array and image for every item that stored in URL inside json from first URL. (want to place item's name,price,category, image in collectionViewCell)
trying to solve it for 3 days (1 question asked on that theme). My mind is melting right now, trying to understand in witch time should i request items and how then download image.

tried to make this viewModel:

```
    public class ShopModel: Codable {
    private let shopItem: ShopItem
    init(item: ShopItem) {
        self.shopItem = item
    }
    
    
    public var category: String {
        shopItem.category!
    }
    public var name: String {
        shopItem.name!
    }
    public var price: Int {
        Int(shopItem.price!)
    }
    var image: UIImage {
        guard let imageURL = URL(string: shopItem.image_url!) else { fatalError("didnt find imageURL") }
                let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: imageURL) { [weak self] data, response, error in
                    guard let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse,
                          (200..<300).contains(httpResponse.statusCode),
                          let self = self else {
                        fatalError()
                    }
                    guard let data = data else {
                        fatalError()
                    }
                    guard let downloadedImage = UIImage(data: data) else { fatalError("didnt load image") }
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.image = downloadedImage
                    }
                }
        task.resume()
    }
    
 
    
    
}

struct ShopItem: Codable {
    let category: String?
    let name: String?
    let price: Double?
    let image_url: String?
}
```

and networkHelper to download items from given URL:

```
    
    var items: [ShopItem] = []
    
    
    let latestURL = URL(string: "https://run.mocky.io/v3/cc0071a1-f06e-48fa-9e90-b1c2a61eaca7")
    let flashSaleURL = URL(string: "https://run.mocky.io/v3/a9ceeb6e-416d-4352-bde6-2203416576ac")
    
    let urlSession = URLSession.shared
    
    func downloadLatest(_ completion: () -> Void) {
        
        guard let latestURL = latestURL else {
            fatalError()
        }
        
            let task = urlSession.dataTask(with: latestURL) { [weak self] data, response, error in
                guard let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse,
                      (200..<300).contains(httpResponse.statusCode),
                      let self = self else {
                    fatalError()
                }
                guard let data = data else {
                    fatalError()
                }
               
               
                    if let results = try? JSONDecoder().decode(ShopModel.self, from: data) {
                        self.items = results.shopItems ?? [ShopItem]()
                        
                    } else {
                        fatalError("hello idiot")
                    }
            }
        task.resume()
//        completion()
        }
    }
```

just trying to download information in custom CollectionView but everytime im getting in a rut.

Comment: "...everytime im getting in a rut.", please add a better explanation of what goes wrong.

Comment: I dont know how to make a model with uiImage(in first question i got unswer to load array of items but with imageURL, not actual image. Need to download all items file and then download images but in what method of ViewController or method of collectionView or else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is to take advantage of `async/await` in Swift 5.5+

In the model declare `imageUrl` in `ShopItem` as URL and add a computed property which loads the image asynchronously.

```
struct ShopItem: Codable {
    let category: String
    let name: String
    let price: Double
    let imageUrl: URL
    
    var image : UIImage? {
        get async throws {
            let (data, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: imageUrl)
            return UIImage(data: data)
        }
    }
}
```

It's beyond the question but I recommend to cache the images to avoid multiple loading of an image in a collection or table view

---

Make `downloadLatest()` `async throws` and add the `convertFromSnakeCase` strategy

```
func downloadLatest() async throws -> [ShopItem] {
    let latestURL = URL(string: "https://run.mocky.io/v3/cc0071a1-f06e-48fa-9e90-b1c2a61eaca7")!
    
    let (data, response) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: latestURL)
    guard let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse,
          (200..<300).contains(httpResponse.statusCode) else
    { throw URLError(.badServerResponse) }
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
    let results = try decoder.decode(ShopModel.self, from: data)
    return results.latest
}
```

To run the code and retrieve an image write

```
Task {
    do {
        let items = try await downloadLatest()
        let firstImage = try await items[0].image
    }  catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

Comment: should i use this "Task" in VC's or CollectionView's method? i tried to download items in viewDidLoad and put them in var "Items" on CollectionView and then in cellForItemAt download every items image but images dont present

Comment: You need the Task wherever you run the code.

Comment: i understood that this Task closure is needed when u are going to use async func, but as i sayed: i tried to download items (with ur solution) from VC, and use them in collectionView's cellForItemAt to populate it with images (imageview.image = try await items[indexPath.row].image. And im getting an error that my array of items is empty. I think i need to make collectionView W8 for items to be downloaded and then retrieve Images from urls, but how?

Comment: Please ask a new question and add the relevant code.